# DatabaseError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes')

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a django project and I would like to run some unit tests. When I try:
`python manage.py test` it throws this error and I couldn't find much information about it in here.

my db settings in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',           
        'PORT': '3306', 
    }
}
```

It looks like something related with `InnoDB` and `MyISAM` but I have no idea what is wrong and how to fix it. Thanks!

django version: 1.5.4
mysql version: 5.5

Also, there is no `unique=True` set in any of the django models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes

Comment: Oh goodness! Somebody is running with a silly key declaration.

Comment: @That1Guy same error, different approachs. I am not creating any ddl on my own

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own solution.

If you have somehow this in your `my.cnf`:

```
 character-set-server = utf8mb4
 collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Then it creates this 'too much bytes' problem. Reverted it back to good old `utf8` and it helped.

Comment: Did not work for me with Mariadb 10 GA, any other solution on your experience? Tried almost everything wihtout results...

Comment: it has been a long time that I tackled with this problem, right now I don't remember anything :-) so goodluck to you.

Comment: I finally could solve it by altering varchar length from index columns to lower than 256 values

Comment: You can do it per database with `CREATE DATABASE <dbname> CHARACTER SET utf8;` (from the [django manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#creating-your-database)). Tested successfully with MariaDB 10.0.27.

Answer (score 11):

solution is

```
ALTER DATABASE `databasename` CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

as already exposed here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43365860/7708836

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the subject issue creating a new database like below:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS databasename;

CREATE DATABASE databasename DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your database using the following command
CREATE DATABASE  CHARACTER SET utf8;