# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes')

Tags: python, django, database, mariadb, migrate

My model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default='course')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024, default='no title')
    foreign_title = models.CharField(max_length=1024, default='no title', blank=True)
    header = models.CharField(max_length=1024, default='', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title
```

I am add "unique_together":

```
class Course(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default='course')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024, default='no title')
    foreign_title = models.CharField(max_length=1024, default='no title', blank=True)
    header = models.CharField(max_length=1024, default='', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['language', 'name', 'title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title
```

In-migration time getting the error:

```
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes')
```

My DB is: 
    mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.17-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

I tried to increase the length of the index mysql:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set global innodb_file_format = BARRACUDA;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> set global innodb_large_prefix = ON;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But this is still not enough:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes')
```

The problem index length. How to specify the length limit Django index?

Comment: I limited myself: unique_together = ['language', 'name'] (it works), but I would like to have: unique_together = ['language', 'name', 'title']

Answer (score 47):

solution is

```
ALTER DATABASE `databasename` CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: I should also note that "utf8" only supports 3 bytes per character! See here: https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434

Answer (score 5):

The previous two answers did not help in my case, so I'm posting my solution to my case when your limit is `1000` (i.e. 1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes').

First of all, make sure you are working on `utf8` encoding!

Then, navigate to your setting file `my.ini`, find the line `default-storage-engine=xxx`. If it is

```
default-storage-engine=MYISAM
```

please change to

```
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

Then, the problem should be solved.

The reason is simply because `MYISAM` does not support key size greater than 1000 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

You can recreate "database" again:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

or change config file. Open /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf and change:

```
character-set-server  = utf8
collation-server      = utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 3):

Just upgrade and migrate database to **MySQL-8.0.11** or ** MySQL-5.7.21** also make sure to use *utf8* and *utf8_general_ci*

I had that problem, then I updated to 8.0.11 on my testing enviroment and 5.7.21 on the server. Now it migrates on both enviroments.

Answer (score 2):

I think all 4 of these things are needed:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = ON,
           innodb_file_format = Barracuda,
           innodb_large_prefix = ON;
CREATE/ALTER TABLE ...
    ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED
```

This should get past the limit of 767 bytes for one column, but won't get past the 3072 bytes limit for the entire index.

In order to have a compound *unique* index composed of strings, normalize some of the strings.  Replacing a long string with a 4-byte INT will shrink the index below the limit.

Comment: Did not help. Anyway: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes').

Comment: @StanZeez - My Answer was written 5 years ago.  Here is what might be an update:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding

```
'OPTIONS': { 'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB;' }
```

to my DB backed configuration in settings.py and that fixed the problem.

The MySQL server was configured to use InnoDB as a default engine, but due to some reason it still tried to create tables with the MyISAM. I am running MySQL 5.1 with Django 2.2.1 and Python 3.6.7

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade mysql to 5.7 and try migrate again.

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.1-1_all.deb  
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.1-1_all.deb  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is one of the top posts for this kind of error I can share my solution that worked for me when storing S3 paths into my db.

I'm adding a MySQL `prefix` index to the desired field.

```
# my_app/models.py
class File(models.Model):
    s3_path = models.CharField(max_length=1024, help_text="S3 object key")


# my_app/migration_000x.py
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        (...),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql="CREATE INDEX my_app_file_s3_path__prefix ON my_app_file (s3_path(768));",
            reverse_sql="DROP INDEX my_app_file_s3_path__prefix ON my_app_file;",
        )
    ]
```

I can get away with this because I know that most of the entries will be quite short (100-200 chars) so they will benefit even from just a prefix index but I still maintain `max_length` that is forced upon me by AWS S3.

I'm using `InnoDB` engine with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for all my tables.

Answer (score 0):

export database from local and import it using command line
like that
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
this worked for me