# "Specified key was too long" error when migrating from sqlite to mysql on pythonanywhere

Tags: mysql, django, pythonanywhere

I am migrating my django webapp from sqlite to mysql on the pythonanywhere platform and I keep getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes')
```

I tried several things including the answer 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782081/django-db-utils-operationalerror-1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-le) but couldn't make it work. Any suggestions?

My models.py file is very simple:

```
from django.db import models

class Showww(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField()
```

and the full error message is:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, shows, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying shows.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 97, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 107, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 36, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 270, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 98, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 128, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/smartadds/.virtualenvs/broadwaypass/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes')
```

Comment: paste your models.py code here.

Comment: I have a simple models.py file: 

class Showww(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField()