# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes') with unique_togther field

Tags: python, mysql, django, phpmyadmin

I am having the same issue as the user from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782081/django-db-utils-operationalerror-1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-le), however, all of the proposed solutions did not work for me. I am using MySQL 8.0.24 with Django 3.1.

Similar to them, I had a model without a `unique_together` field as shown below

```
class Show(models.Model):
    english_name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    kanji_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    romanji_name = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    show_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    # a bunch of other fields...


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Series'
        ordering = ('-created',)
unique_together = ['english_name', 'kanji_name', 'romanji_name', 'show_type']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.english_name
```

It was only until I changed `class Meta` to this

```
class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Series'
        ordering = ('-created',)
        unique_together = ['english_name', 'kanji_name', 'romanji_name', 'show_type']
```

That  I started receiving this error whenever I migrated my database.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes')
```

I followed the steps in the post I linked above to ensure the utf8 was used, I was able to confirm that the dataset was using that character set, but it didn't resolve my issue. Is there anything else I can do to ensure that the `unique_together` field can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to get rid of that field and instead check the database using `exists()` whenever uploading a spreadsheet of data to ensure that duplicate entries aren't made.