# Laravel Composite Index Issue

Tags: laravel, indexing, composite, composite-index

I checked this solution. 
[#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes)
But I want to know how to do this in laravel migration file as I can't do it directly in mysql, I need a solution which can change the length of the index columns in migration file.

```
KEY `index` (`parent_menu_id`,`menu_link`(50),`plugin`(50),`alias`(50))
```

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes)

Comment: `$table->index([ "key1", \DB::raw("key2(50)")]);` might work.