# Can't extract ResultSet, related to String as

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Error messages in spring:

```
: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table category_class (category_name varchar(255) not null, primary key (category_name)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement



: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table book_class add constraint FKqov24n7bmx5f0s8d74tdxbgbk foreign key (book_category) references category_class (category_name)" via JDBC Statement
```

Can't exact result set using Spring Boot with Hibernate.

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'myDatabase.category_class' doesn't exist
```

All my other tables are displayed correctly, however my category class does have a string as PK, which may be the cause of the issue. 
The Error occurs when I try to acess the mysql database with findAll through my categoryService and CategoryRepository which extends JPARepository.

--Category.java--

```
package myPackage;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="category_class")
public class Category {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "categoryName")
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
        private List<Book> books;
}
```

--application.properties--

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oblig2_v3
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=8080
```

Does anyone know why my table is not getting created in MySQL?

EDIT: Book class added && cleanup.

---Book.java---

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="book_class")
public class Book {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long ISBN; //PK
        private String title;
        private String releaseYear;
        private int quantity;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name ="book_category")
        private Category category;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name ="author")
        private Author author;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
        private List<Order> orders;

}
```

Comment: is the table really named `category_class` or just `category`

Comment: the error message is quite clear: *Table 'myDatabase.category_class' doesn't exist*

Comment: @Lino Yes, the table is really named 'category_class'. Used to be 'CATEGORY' but changed it to check if mysql's lowercase convertion was the reason for the table to now show up. Was afraid changing it to 'category' in lowercase would interfere with the '@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category"). If I can pinpoint the issue, the table will problably be changed back to 'category'

Comment: This is related to a part of your error message (`Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes`) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes . You may want to avoid having a VARCHAR column as a PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to having a `VARCHAR` as `PK` as @Arnaud stated. Since I didn't want to change my PK, I followed the link provided: [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes)

And did the quick fix from one of the answers, creating a database in mysql with:

`create database my_db character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;` 
solved my issue.

The link provided should be helpful for anyone else facing similar issues. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the property

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop  or update
```

The problem in your case is that you already have the database created and it does not make an attempt to update it.

You have two options:

1. Use Update, this will make spring browse the metadata of your schema and try to apply the nessesary changes.
2. Drop and re-create the schema each time - this may be desireable in the development phase or in unit/integration test scenarios.

According to spring documentation ,the following values of this property are valid:

> You can set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto explicitly and the standard
>   Hibernate property values are none, validate, update, create, and
>   create-drop. Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on
>   whether it thinks your database is embedded. It defaults to
>   create-drop if no schema manager has been detected or none in all
>   other cases. An embedded database is detected by looking at the
>   Connection type. hsqldb, h2, and derby are embedded, and others are
>   not. Be careful when switching from in-memory to a ‘real’ database
>   that you do not make assumptions about the existence of the tables and
>   data in the new platform. You either have to set ddl-auto explicitly
>   or use one of the other mechanisms to initialize the database.

Comment: Don't think that this answers the question, the error message is still `Table 'myDatabase.category_class' doesn't exist`, so it was never created in the first place

Comment: @Lino . you don't understand, spring is checking if something has bean created. In this case your schema. When it finds out that something has been created it does not attempt at all to run the re-create. Just try what I told you and you will see.  In your case you want to update an already existing schema.

Comment: @Lino You are expecting UPDATE behaviour from CREATE behaviour. It does not work this way.

Comment: This did not seem to solve the issue. However I uploaded a springBoot error which states `GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table book_class add constraint FKqov24n7bmx5f0s8d74tdxbgbk foreign key (book_category) references category_class (category_name)" via JDBC Statement` on startup

Comment: Tried Both, the errors seems to be caused by the PK. See the Spring warnings added to top of post.

Comment: @froffen It is hard to tell if you don't see the exact exception that is thrown ? Can you enable tracing and see what is the exact exception ?