# Error : 1071, Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, innodb

I want to import a sql file in my database getting this error `1071, Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes`

here is my code for related table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `model_has_permissions`;

CREATE TABLE `model_has_permissions` (
  `permission_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `model_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `model_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`permission_id`,`model_id`,`model_type`),
  KEY `model_has_permissions_model_id_model_type_index` (`model_id`,`model_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `model_has_permissions_permission_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `permissions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: This question has the answer here[1072 specified key was too long.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747703/8240120)

Comment: `utf8mb4` uses up to _four_ bytes to store a character, so `varchar(255)` gets you up to  1,020 already.

Comment: I am reopening this because the "dup" answer does not apply.  You can't use prefix indexing on the `PRIMARY KEY` without causing more problems.

Answer (score 2):

Plan A:  Don't use more than 191 for number of characters in `model_type`.

Plan B:  Normalize `model_type`.

Plan C:  Change `model_type` to `CHARACTER SET ascii, if appropriate.

Other options:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes