# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: laravel, voyager

I'm trying to install laravel voyager but getting this error.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
> was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `users`
> add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

This is my \app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

This is my config\database.php

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'prefix_indexes' => true,
'strict' => true,
'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
```

AND MY DB HAS COLATION **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

you can increase that

```
SET @@global.innodb_large_prefix = 1;
```

for example

```sql
mysql> set global innodb_large_prefix = ON;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: where do I set that?

Comment: connect to  your db and exec this code ... in console

Comment: do you use InnoDB engine storage?

Comment: I use phpmyadmin for localhost

Comment: run it the same as you do select * from foo

Comment: probably you did the wrong set of the collection ...

Answer (score -1):

A similar error is described here.

> https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

there is also information here

> [Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa)
> Successful programming = )