# Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I was trying to add a unique index in a Laravel migration.

```php
Schema::table('pending_tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unique(['actionable_id', 'actionable_type', 'step'], 'unique_tasks');
});
```

I got this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
> (SQL: `alter table 1pending_tasks, add unique 'unique_tasks'('actionable_id', 'actionable_type', step'`)).

What could the issue be?

I have the engine set to `InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`.

Inside `AppServiceProvider.php` I have added:

```php
public function boot() {
     //...

     Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

     //...
}
```

---

Edit: Here is the `show create table pending_tasks`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `pending_tasks` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `actionable_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `actionable_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `actors` json NOT NULL,
  `property_id` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `step` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `comparable_options` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `preview` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `action_options` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `actor` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `selected_option` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `actor_comment` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `queued_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `approvable_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `request` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `pending_tasks_actionable_type_actionable_id_index` (`actionable_type`,`actionable_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please post `show create table 1pending_tasks` , it seems that your indexes have exceeded the maximum allowed length.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I have added it.

Comment: The answer provided by Bill on  [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes) will give you an idea how to solve . Also use InnoDB not MyISAM storage engine, apart from the pros maximum length is 3072 https://dbfiddle.uk/-W5BxieM